# Using God monitor unicorn for rails but permission error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, permissions, unicorn, god

I am new to `God`. I am trying to using `God` to monitor `unicorn` process on which my rails application runs.

Here's my God file:

```
rails_env = ENV["RAILS_ENV"]
APP_ROOT = '/home/deployer/deploy/myproject'
RAILS_ROOT = "#{APP_ROOT}/current"

God.watch do |w|
  w.name = "myproject"
  w.interval = 30.seconds
  w.dir = RAILS_ROOT

  w.start = "cd #{RAILS_ROOT} && bundle exec unicorn_rails -E #{rails_env} -c #{RAILS_ROOT}/config/unicorn.rb -D"
  w.stop = "kill -s QUIT `cat #{RAILS_ROOT}/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid`"
  w.restart = "kill -s USR2 `cat #{RAILS_ROOT}/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid`"

  w.start_grace = 20.seconds
  w.restart_grace = 20.seconds
  w.pid_file = "#{RAILS_ROOT}/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid"
  w.log = "#{RAILS_ROOT}/log/unicorn.god.log"

  w.uid = 'deployer'
  w.gid = 'staff'

  w.behavior(:clean_pid_file)

  w.start_if do |start|
    start.condition(:process_running) do |c|
      c.interval = 5.seconds
      c.running = false
    end
  end

  w.restart_if do |restart|
    restart.condition(:memory_usage) do |c|
      c.above = 300.megabytes
      c.times = [3, 5] # 3 out of 5 intervals
    end

    restart.condition(:cpu_usage) do |c|
      c.above = 50.percent
      c.times = 5
end
```

end
end

But when I dry-run to test if the config file is valid with `god -c config/unicorn.god -D`, I get the following error:

```
$ god -c config/unicorn.god -D
I [2013-02-07 23:51:23]  INFO: Loading config/unicorn.god
I [2013-02-07 23:51:23]  INFO: Syslog enabled.
I [2013-02-07 23:51:23]  INFO: Using pid file directory: /home/deployer/.god/pids
E [2013-02-07 23:51:23] ERROR: PID file directory '/home/deployer/deploy/myproject/current/tmp/pids' is not writable by deployer
E [2013-02-07 23:51:23] ERROR: Log directory '/home/deployer/deploy/myproject/current/log' is not writable by deployer
E [2013-02-07 23:51:23] ERROR: Task 'myproject' is not valid (see above)
```

But actually I have the permission to those two dirs with user `deployer`:

```
~/deploy/myproject/current$ ls -l
lrwxrwxrwx 1 deployer staff   42 Feb  7 23:24 log -> /home/deployer/deploy/myproject/shared/log

~/deploy/myproject/current/tmp$ ls -l
lrwxrwxrwx 1 deployer staff   43 Feb  7 23:24 pids -> /home/deployer/deploy/myproject/shared/pids
```

and the god process is also running under `deployer`:

```
$ ps -ef | grep god
deployer   381     1  5 00:20 pts/0    00:00:00 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327-falcon@global/bin/god
```

Why is that?

Comment: have you find a solution ? I have the exact same issue ...

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem.
When I removed the `w.gid` line, things started working fine.